# How do I subset columns in a pandas dataframe from a list in another frame which includes NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the dataframe that needs subsetting:

```
df1: 
    A    B    C
0   1    3    1
1   0    4    1
2   3    1    1
3   2   -6    1
4   8    1   -1
5   10   0    9
.   .    .    .
.   .    .    .
.   .    .    .
[Frame Continues]
```

My reference frame:

```
df2:
    Names    Year
0     A       3
1     C       4
2     NaN     3
3     NaN     1
4     NaN     3
```

What I want:

```
df3:
    A    C
0   1    1
1   0    1
2   3    1
3   2    1
4   8   -1
5   10   9
.   .    .
.   .    . 
.   .    .
[Frame Continues]
```

The `.`s at the end of the frames mean the continuation of the frame to some length.

The frame has a single integer index. As shown on the left of the frames.

I tried: `d3 = d1[d2["Names"]]` but then got an error which said `Cannot index with vector containing NA/NaN values`.

I also tried `d3 = d1[d2["Names"].tolist()]`. Said `[nan nan nan] not in index`

Is there a way to make pandas skip the NaNs?

Comment: `df1[df2.Names.dropna()]` use `dropna()` to drop missing values?

Comment: Wow. That was simple. Worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.filter` to do this which'll automatically handle `NaN`s and makes it quite explicit your intent is subsetting the columns, eg:

```
df1.filter(df2.Names)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is more comprehensive.